# {"message":"CSRF token missing or incorrect","status":"fail"} i am getting error how can i fix it?

Tags: php, curl, instagram, instagram-api, php-curl

I'm trying to login to Instagram using php curl, but I'm getting an error like this {"message":"CSRF token missing or incorrect","status":"fail"} how can I fix it?

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/web/accounts/login/ajax/";
$ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 105.0.0.11.118 (iPhone11,8; iOS 12_3_1; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 828x1792; 165586599)";
$curl = curl_init();

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Get the response headers
$headerSize = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $headerSize);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $header, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $cookie) {
    if (strpos($cookie, 'csrftoken=') === 0) {
        list(, $csrftoken) = explode('=', $cookie, 2);
        break;
    }
}
curl_close($curl);
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'user-agent:' . $ua,
    'x-csrftoken:' . $csrftoken
);

$payload = array(
    'enc_password' => '#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:0:password',
    'optIntoOneTap' => false,
    'queryParams' => json_encode((object)[]),
    'username' => 'username'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);

$sonuc = curl_exec($ch); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($headers);
echo "</pre>";
echo $sonuc;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

When I run this code, the output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 105.0.0.11.118 (iPhone11,8; iOS 12_3_1; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 828x1792; 165586599)
    [1] => x-csrftoken:V1WIGArKhLUTW1cCUcIGiBjc9sIE0kd4
)
{"message":"CSRF token missing or incorrect","status":"fail"}
```

I have no idea how to fix this error, I would be very happy if you could help.